# Ruby on rails and Heroku problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

```
$ git push heroku master
```

I basically get this error message.

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:falling-stone-505.git'
```

I'm very new to computer programming and ruby on rails so an "idiots" guide to solving this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22):

You haven't committed anything to push yet. Try doing:

```
$ git add -A
$ git commit
```

Then try to push to Heroku again.

You might try following along with [this tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning), although I can't vouch for it. Most of the professional endeavors in this space are books.

Comment: @user605116 , you may also want to try railsforzombies.org . It starts at a pretty basic level and it's entertaining.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your commits to be easier to track in the future, after

1.

```
$ git add -A
```

2.

instead of

```
$ git commit
```

you can use

```
$ git commit -m "add a message here such as FIRST COMMIT or PROBLEM WITH CONTACTS VIEW ADDRESS VARIABLE TYPO FIXED."
```

3.
Then you can

```
$ git push heroku master
```